# Error while generating report in apache-jmeter-5.4.1.tgz

Tags: jmeter

sh jmeter.sh -n -t filePath.jmx -l outFilePath.jtl -e -o folderPath

```
Error generating the report: org.apache.jmeter.report.dashboard.GenerationException: Error while processing samples: Consumer failed with message :Consumer failed with message :Consumer failed with message :Consumer failed with message :Begin size 0 is not equal to fixed size 5
```

In resume

```
Consumer failed with message :Begin size 0 is not equal to fixed size 5
```

- currently using Java version "17" 2021-09-14 LTS
- MacOS big SUR version 11.4
- the properties files are fresh and values are equal to the default ones
- [Jmeter 5.4.1](https://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi)
- outFile.jtl

```
timeStamp,elapsed,label,responseCode,responseMessage,threadName,dataType,success,failureMessage,bytes,sentBytes,grpThreads,allThreads,URL,Latency,IdleTime,Connect
1632430450882,1117,HTTP Request,200,OK,FIRST_Jmeter_Test 1-3,text,true,,3824,557,3,3,Url_hidden,1111,0,256
1632430450448,1755,HTTP Request,200,OK,FIRST_Jmeter_Test 1-2,text,true,,3836,557,3,3,Url_hidden,1755,0,690
1632430450448,1755,HTTP Request,200,OK,FIRST_Jmeter_Test 1-1,text,true,,3828,557,3,3,Url_hidden,1755,0,690
1632430452312,585,HTTP Request,200,OK,FIRST_Jmeter_Test 1-2,text,true,,3836,557,3,3,Url_hidden,585,0,144
1632430452238,758,HTTP Request,200,OK,FIRST_Jmeter_Test 1-3,text,true,,3832,557,3,3,Url_hidden,757,0,137
1632430452301,806,HTTP Request,200,OK,FIRST_Jmeter_Test 1-1,text,true,,3828,557,3,3,Url_hidden,805,0,136
1632430452962,550,HTTP Request,200,OK,FIRST_Jmeter_Test 1-2,text,true,,3824,557,3,3,Url_hidden,550,0,152
1632430453328,593,HTTP Request,200,OK,FIRST_Jmeter_Test 1-1,text,true,,3828,557,2,2,Url_hidden,592,0,135
1632430453276,815,HTTP Request,200,OK,FIRST_Jmeter_Test 1-3,text,true,,3840,557,1,1,Url_hidden,814,0,142
```

The thread run successfully and the jtl file is created as well.

I quite new on Jmeter and tried to see where that "size" attribute is currently locate to see how change it, but could not find it on any *.properties file

any though how can be this fixed, what the message is referring to?

thanks

Comment: I have the same issue with a fresh install. I will try have a poke around to see what I can find out

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue with a brand new install of jmeter. macOS 10.14.6 / java 17 2021-09-14 LTS

Comment: same issue on windows with Java 17. I've installed Java 16 and now is all good

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This error is likely due to an incompatibility of JMeter with Java 17 (as mentioned by Dmitri T).

Whilst we wait for a fix, a workaround would be downgrading to Java 16. I can confirm this solved the issue for me.

Comment: Anyone have suggestions on how to do this on macOS? It's a nightmare... EDIT: Ah nice, Java 16 has been suspended, though perhaps by now this bug is fixed in Java 17?

Comment: Still getting this error with Java 16.0 and JMeter 5.4.3

Comment: I had to edit jmeter.sh to hardcode a JDK < 17, as the script was still picking up JDK 17 on my system. That fixed it. JDK 13 worked this way.

Comment: it's fixed in jmeter 5.5

Comment: I'm still finding the issue in jmeter 5.5.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with:

- MacOS big SUR version 11.6
- Jmeter 5.4.1 (installed via brew)
- Temurin 11 (LTS) OpenJDK & Temurin 8 (LTS) OpenJDK

Running Jmeter with Java 8 solved my issue. The problem was, that Jmeter always used Java 11. I struggled some days to find out, how to set the Jmeter Java version:

- set the correct Java 8 Home in: /usr/local/Cellar/jmeter/5.4.1/bin/jmeter:

  JAVA_HOME=$JAVA_8_HOME exec "/usr/local/Cellar/jmeter/5.4.1/libexec/bin/jmeter"  "$@"

Maybe there are easier ways to set Java 8 for Jmeter - but this was the only solution which worked for me.

Comment: Can you clarify what this does? I beleive my JMeter is also always using the wrong java version, even if I declare JAVA_HOME before calling it

Comment: I had to edit jmeter.sh to hardcode a JDK < 17, as the script was still picking up JDK 17 on my system, no matter what JAVA_HOME was setup beforehand. Editing jmeter.sh with `export JAVA_HOME=<JDK path>`  fixed it. JDK 13 worked this way.

Answer (score 1):

I had Java 8 installed however, the JMeter was picking up Java 1.17 which was nowhere in my system. So uninstalling and reinstalling jmeter, worked like a charm for me.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce your issue using:

1. [`openjdk:8-jre-alpine` docker image](https://hub.docker.com/_/openjdk)
2. [JMeter 5.4.1](https://archive.apache.org/dist/jmeter/binaries/apache-jmeter-5.4.1.tgz)
3. Test plan [`Test.jmx`](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/rel/v5.4.1/extras/Test.jmx) from [extras](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/tree/rel/v5.4.1/extras) folder of JMeter

Demo:

[image]

If you cannot reproduce the above behaviour I think you made some changes either to [Results File Configuration](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#results_file_config) or to [Reporting Configuration](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#reporting) or both so you need to inspect all the [JMeter Properties](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization) which differ from the defaults and restore their values to the original ones.

If you need further support you need to share at least first 2 lines of your outFilePath.jtl results file. Better if possible the full file and all the .properties files from JMeter's "bin" folder.

Comment: I have the same issue as the poster with a fresh install.

Comment: It looks like Java 17 causing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

exec commandline /usr/libexec/java_home -V
[image]

replace bin of jmeter JAVA_HOME
[image]

and then ,it is success.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).