# Not able to generate report at end of Jmeter test

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

I saw a similar question here : [Error while generating report in apache-jmeter-5.4.1.tgz](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69294826/error-while-generating-report-in-apache-jmeter-5-4-1-tgz#), but nothing seems to be working. Not sure if there is a fix already in place.

I am using Apache Jmeter 5.4.1, MacOS (Big Sur) and Java version 1.8.0_311.

When I am running the jmeter in nonGUI moe, while generating the report, I am getting following error :

```
Error generating the report: org.apache.jmeter.report.dashboard.GenerationException: Error while processing samples: Consumer failed with message :Consumer failed with message :Consumer failed with message :Consumer failed with message :Begin size 1 is not equal to fixed size 5
... end of run
```

The log file suggests this error :

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Begin size 1 is not equal to fixed size 5
    at java.util.stream.Nodes$FixedNodeBuilder.begin(Nodes.java:1214) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.stream.Sink$ChainedReference.begin(Sink.java:253) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.stream.SliceOps$1$1.begin(SliceOps.java:192) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.stream.SortedOps$SizedRefSortingSink.end(SortedOps.java:354) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel(AbstractPipeline.java:528) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:513) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:575) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluateToArrayNode(AbstractPipeline.java:260) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.toArray(ReferencePipeline.java:616) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.jmeter.report.processor.Top5ErrorsSummaryData.getTop5ErrorsMetrics(Top5ErrorsSummaryData.java:82) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]
    at org.apache.jmeter.report.processor.Top5ErrorsBySamplerConsumer.createDataResult(Top5ErrorsBySamplerConsumer.java:97) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]
    at org.apache.jmeter.report.processor.Top5ErrorsBySamplerConsumer.createDataResult(Top5ErrorsBySamplerConsumer.java:29) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]
    at org.apache.jmeter.report.processor.AbstractSummaryConsumer.createResultFromKey(AbstractSummaryConsumer.java:200) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]
    at org.apache.jmeter.report.processor.AbstractSummaryConsumer.stopConsuming(AbstractSummaryConsumer.java:261) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]
    at org.apache.jmeter.report.processor.AbstractSampleConsumer.stopProducing(AbstractSampleConsumer.java:241) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]
    at org.apache.jmeter.report.processor.FilterConsumer.stopConsuming(FilterConsumer.java:111) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]
    at org.apache.jmeter.report.processor.AbstractSampleConsumer.stopProducing(AbstractSampleConsumer.java:241) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]
    at org.apache.jmeter.report.processor.FilterConsumer.stopConsuming(FilterConsumer.java:111) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]
    at org.apache.jmeter.report.processor.AbstractSampleConsumer.stopProducing(AbstractSampleConsumer.java:241) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]
    at org.apache.jmeter.report.processor.NormalizerSampleConsumer.stopConsuming(NormalizerSampleConsumer.java:125) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]
    at org.apache.jmeter.report.processor.CsvFileSampleSource$PrivateProducer.stopProducing(CsvFileSampleSource.java:335) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]
    at org.apache.jmeter.report.processor.CsvFileSampleSource.produce(CsvFileSampleSource.java:182) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]
    at org.apache.jmeter.report.processor.CsvFileSampleSource.run(CsvFileSampleSource.java:235) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]
    at org.apache.jmeter.report.dashboard.ReportGenerator.generate(ReportGenerator.java:240) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]
```

Can someone please suggest me what went wrong or if I missed something?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you give a try with JDK 1.8 versions ?

Comment: I tried with JDK 1.8 only.

Comment: Sorry it has to be checked with 1.8+ versions

Comment: @JaneshKodikara Can you be more specific which version actually worked for you, because I have tried already with Java 17 (Latest) and it seems to be not working with as well.

Comment: I am still on Catalina , JMeter 5.4.1 and JDK `"1.8.0_292`. It was just a suggestion not an answer/solution.

Comment: This error was reproducible on BigSur with JDK 17. There was no issue with `1.8.0_311-b11`.  Do you have any other JDK installed on your machine ? Have you changed any of JAVA_HOME settings in JMeter ?

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue with JDK 17.0.1, JMeter 5.4.1, MacOS Monterey. I was able to resolve the issue by uninstalling JDK 17 (see [instructions here](https://explainjava.com/uninstall-java-macos/) how to uninstall in Mac), then [download](https://java.com/en/download/manual.jsp) and install JRE instead.