# While generate HTML report via cmd show error

Tags: jmeter

Error generating the report: org.apache.jmeter.report.dashboard.GenerationException: Error while processing samples: Consumer failed with message :Consumer failed with message :Consumer failed with message :Consumer failed with message :Begin size 0 is not equal to fixed size 5

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error while generating report in apache-jmeter-5.4.1.tgz](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69294826/error-while-generating-report-in-apache-jmeter-5-4-1-tgz)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a JMeter bug, I think you should report it via [JMeter Bugzilla](https://jmeter.apache.org/issues.html)

[image]

Try downgrading to i.e. [Java 8](https://openjdk.java.net/projects/jdk8/) (the minimum Java version you can run [JMeter 5.4](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/introducing-jmeter5-4-new-features-and-abilities/) with) and it should resolve your issue.